# Reduce number of subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 2 tables `emp` and `expenditure`.

**Emp:**

> ID, NAME

**Expenditure:**

> ID, EMP_ID, AMOUNT

Each emp has a limit of 100 that he/she can spend. We want to check which emp has expenditure > 100.

Output attributes needed: *Emp name, exp id, amount*

**My query:**

```
SELECT E.NAME,
    EXP.ID,
    EXP.AMOUNT
FROM EMP E
INNER JOIN expenditure EXP ON E.ID = EXP.EMP_ID
WHERE E.ID in
        (SELECT EMP_ID
            FROM
                (SELECT EMP_ID,
                        SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL
                    FROM expenditure
                    GROUP BY EMP_ID
                    HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 100.00
                    ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) SUBQ)
ORDER BY EXP.AMOUNT desc;
```

Is it possible to optimize this?

Comment: what's the current version of the database?

Comment: You cannot have an exp.id in the results as you are aggregating records from exp table.

Comment: @nazim: That's why there is a subquery.

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in the subquery looks ineffective. Without it, don't select `SUM(AMOUNT)` and don't nest subqueries. (The outer `ORDER BY` orders by *single* expenditure, interleaving employees - not what I would want.)

Comment: Just to note - this question is also found at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/275110, where it is a better fit than here.

Comment: @greybeard I noticed the question is a bit misleading especially when question is targeted on optimization and sub-query structure. The original query spits out "every line" of expense of an employee, whose "total" expenses are above 100. The question text however, says "Which employee has gone above 100". These are two different questions. My answer below is for the latter "Who has gone above". It will NOT list all expenses of employees who had spent over 100, but only a list of employees who have gone above 100 and their **TOTAL EXPENDITURE** (not each line of expense).

Answer (score 2):

Just like code, SQL queries can be written in many different ways. Run an Execution Plan on your SQL. [Check here](https://www.sqlshack.com/explore-the-secrets-of-sql-server-execution-plans/) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?channel=crow5&client=firefox-b-d&q=sql+query+optimisers)

Below is more "conciser" version although it may not be any more optimised than your current code. Use Execution Plans to analyse performance.

```
SELECT E.NAME,
    E.ID, -- THIS IS EMPLOYEE ID NOT EXPENDITURE ID
    EXP.EMP_SPENT
FROM EMP E
JOIN (SELECT EMP_ID, sum(AMOUNT) as EMP_SPENT FROM expenditure GROUP BY EMP_ID) EXP 
    ON E.ID = EXP.EMP_ID
WHERE EXP.EMP_SPENT > 100;
```

**Additionally...**
I noticed that question is a bit confusing. The original query spits out "every line" of expense of an employee, whose "total" expenses are above 100. The text however, says "Which employee has gone above 100". These are two different questions. My answer above is for the latter "Who has gone above". It will NOT list all expenses of employees who had spent over 100, but only a list of employees who have gone above 100 and their total expenditure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple aggregation with `HAVING` clause such as

```sql
SELECT e.name, e.id, SUM(amount) AS total
  FROM emp e
  JOIN expenditure ep
    ON e.id = ep.emp_id
 GROUP BY e.name, e.id
HAVING SUM(amount) > 100
```

but it's not logical to have a non-aggregated column along with aggregated ones within the result